How to Modify PHP Code to Replace Existing SQL Entry Instead of Creating Duplicate?
I have been tasked with fixing some PHP code for a website and believe I found the main snippet that is causing the frustration. When an employee is hired they are entered into the system and given a number which in our SQL DB is known as a "rosterID". In the event they quit and get rehired, they need to get a new number (rosterID). However, in the rehire process, the website code that I am responsible for fixing creates a new entry, therefore leaving two entries for the same person, an old and new rosterID. I am strugging with the correct command in order to prevent this.
Is there a way I can create a line that will replace the old entry with the new entry? Or is there way that when a new entry is made that the old entry is deleted?
Currently, the website will categorize the two rosterID numbers as "old" and "new".
Thank you!
Snippet of problem code:
// If there's a double entry, throw a submission error and don't add this entry to sql table
if(sqlsrv_num_rows($stmtGet) > 0) {
    // If recertification box is checked, add new record as 'current' and update previous record as 'old'
    if (isset($_GET['recertify'])) {
        if ($Station != "" and $Trainee_Name != "" and $Trainer_Name != "" and $date != "") {
            $updatesql = "UPDATE $certifications SET $certifications.[Recertification] = '$updateCert' 
                WHERE $certifications.[Roster ID] = '$rosterID' AND $certifications.[Station] = '$Station' AND $certifications.[Recertification] = '$Recert'";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO $certifications ([Roster ID], Station, Trainer_Name, Date, Recertification) VALUES
                ('$rosterID', '$Station', '$Trainer_Name', '$date', '$Recert')";
 
            if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $updatesql) AND sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)){
                        ?><p> <?php echo $Trainee_Name;?> has successfully been recertified at <?php echo $Station;?>.</p><?php
 
            } else{
                if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
                    foreach( $errors as $error ) {
                        echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
                        echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
                        echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Submission Failed. Please try again.";

        } 

What I want to happen is when there is an old entry in SQL Server, I want the new entry to replace that old entry. So there will only be one "rosterID" instead of their being the old and new one. Whether that be through the old value being replaced or deleted.

What do you WANT to happen?  Do you want to remove all traces of the older entry?  Wouldn't you want to keep that around for historical purposes?  Perhaps you need an "active" boolean field.

What criteria are you using to determine existence of a rehired employee? What is the primary key of the Roster table? Your posted code doesn't reference the Roster table.

Forgive me if I misunderstood your question but based on what I am seeing, your code right now appears to be both updating the old existing record as well as inserting a new one.
So if your intention is to "replace the old entry with the new entry", wouldn't you delete the old existing record instead of updating?
For example
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;

